# Can't use assigned variables after command

Tags: shell-scripting, command

I have the following script

```
filename="network_list.txt"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    ping_stat=$(ping -c 4 $name 2>&1)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then 
            echo "server $name is down"
        else 
            echo "server $name is up and running"
        fi
done < "$filename"
```

But its output is unexpected and coming as **`"is up and running01"`** **`"is up and running02"`** ..
**`network_list.txt`** file format is like

```
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.102
192.168.1.103
192.168.1.104
192.168.1.105
```

I just need to have a **`ping test`** on these serverss.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your error with bash-4.3.43-4.fc25. It works fine in my case

Comment: The script is working on centos 7 , but am working in ubuntu

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and which version of bash?

Comment: ubuntu  12.04 and GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release-(i686-pc-linux-gnu)